# Python help Advanced Objects: Special Methods

Tags: python

I am hoping someone can give me some advice on my code?
I am learning python via a self study course and one of the assgnments requirements is as below:

create a program named centipede.py, including a class named "Centipede." This class has the following requirements:

1. Once instantiated if called with a value, it appends that argument to an internal list:

   ```
   >>> from centipede import Centipede
   >>> ralph = Centipede()
   >>> ralph('pretzel')
   >>> ralph.stomach
   ['pretzel']
   ```
2. If you print() the class, it returns a comma-delimited string of the internal list:

   ```
   >>> ralph('pickles')
   >>> print(ralph)
   'pretzel,pickles'
   ```
3. Each time an attribute is set on the centipede object, it appends the name of the attribute to another internal list:

   ```
   >>> ralph.shoes = 100 
   >>> ralph.hat = 1
   >>> ralph.legs['shoes', 'hat']
   ```
4. The representation of the centipede object must be a comma-delimited string of this second internal list.

   ```
   >>> ralph
   'shoes,hat'
   ```

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
class MixIns:    
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        print("ATTR: setting attribute {0!r} to {1!r}".format(key, value))
        self.__dict__[key] = value


    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print("ATTR: getting attribute {0!r}".format(key))
        self.__setattr__(key, "No value")
        return "No value"



class Centipede(MixIns):
    legs = []
    stomach = []

    def __init__(self):

        MixIns.__init__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __call__(self, *args):
        [self.stomach.append(arg) for arg in args]

    def __repr__(self):
        return ','.join(self.legs)
```

These are the outcomes of running the code above via the command-line:

1. Sort of works I can create an instance but can't set the attribute
2. Print doesn't display a list
3. I can set the attributes but 'ralph.legs' doesn't return anything
4. Doesn't work

I can't figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Code is format by indenting it with four spaces. 8 in lists.

Comment: BTW, a tip: In your `__call__` method, you're using a list comprehension to append arguments to another list. This means you're creating another list the size of `args` (filled with `None`, because that's what `append` returns with each call) to append stuff on a list, thus wasting memory for no reason. You should replace that with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 5):

- **`legs` and `stomach` have to be assigned in the constructor**. If you assign them at class level, they are class variables (roughly equivalent to java's static members). Do it like this

  ```
  def __init__(self):
       self.legs = []
       self.stomach = []
  ```
- **your `__call__` method is a little too complicated.** this should be enough:

  ```
  def __call__(self, item):
        self.stomach.append(item)
  ```
- **if you `print` an object, it gets converted via `__str__`**. You can try that with

  ```
  class Tester(object):
      def __str__(self):
          return 'str'
  print Tester()
  ```

  so, your `__str__` has to return the joined `stomach`
- **why the mixin?** The magic methods should work without mixins. also, im not sure what you are trying to accomplish in `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation keppla  the __getattr__ and __setattr__ is there to show me what's happening in the magic methods.

Comment: There's no need to put `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` in a separate class, you can put them in the Centipede. Also, you call `__setattr__` in `__getattr__`, that seems strange. As i understand your assignment, you just need __setattr__, to append the name to `legs`.

Comment: OK thanks I'll go through my code and make the changes as suggested just to be clear for the  __str__ should return the following:   'code'return ','.join(self.stomach)?

Comment: OK I'll make the changes to my code just to be clear the **__str__** should return the following:  **return ','.join(self.stomach)?**

Comment: yes, i think that would be correct. just try it, as long as the specifications (your points 1-4) are met, how
exactly you solved the problem is more a question of style.